# Download files with wget. If wget downloads files, move them, otherwise use wget to download different files

Tags: shell, if-statement, wget

I am trying to run a shell script that includes if statements and a set of initial conditions. If wget downloads the files, I would like the script to check if the files with the "grib2" extension exists in the folder. if the files do exist, then it moves them to another directory. If after running wget the files don't download or exist in the directory, then I would like wget to download from a different source. The script is meant to filter.

The issue I am encountering is the second wget script never runs, even if there are zero files with that extension in the folder.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# variables
#

basedir="ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com"
basename1="hur/prod/hur."

date=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
date1=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "+1 days"`
date2=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "-1 days"`
hour=`date +"%H"`
file=`ls -l /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/*.grib2 2>/dev/null`
#
# main
#

if [ $hour -ge "13" ] && [ $hour -le "18" ]
then
datetime="${date}12"
url1="${basedir}/${basename1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*9*l*.0p16.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/ $url1 
   if [[ "$file" != "0" ]]; then
   mv /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/* /awips2/edex/data/manual/
   else [[ "$file" != "1" ]]; then
   wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*0*l*.0p16.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/ $url1
   mv /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/* /awips2/edex/data/manual/
   fi



elif [ $hour -ge "19" ] && [ $hour -le "23" ]
then
datetime="${date}18"
url1="${basedir}/${basename1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*9*l*.0p16.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/ $url1 
   if [[ "$file" != "0" ]]; then
   mv /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/* /awips2/edex/data/manual/
   else [[ "$file" != "1" ]]; then
   wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A   '*0*l*.0p16.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/ $url1
   mv /awips2/edex/data/gfdl/* /awips2/edex/data/manual/
   fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes

- your code is highly repetitive, and will benefit from functions
- the way to assign to `$files` will not give you a count. Plus your value never gets updated.
- you need `elif`

A rewrite

```
#!/bin/bash

basedir="ftp://ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com"
basename1="hur/prod/hur."
download_dir=/awips2/edex/data/gfdl
files_dir=/awips2/edex/data/manual

read date hour <(date +"%Y%m%d %_H")
date1=$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "+1 days")
date2=$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "-1 days")

count_grib2_files() {
    files=( "$download_dir"/*.grib2 )
    # spit out the number of files
    echo "${#files[@]}"
}

do_wget() {
    wget -r -nd --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A "$2" -P "$download_dir" "$1"
}

getfiles() {
    datetime="${date}$1"
    url="${basedir}/${basename1}${datetime}/"
    do_wget "$url" '*9*l*.0p16.*.grib2'
    if [[ "$(count_grib2_files)" -gt 0 ]]; then
        mv "$download_dir"/* "$files_dir"
    else
        do_wget "$url" '*0*l*.0p16.*.grib2'
        if [[ "$(count_grib2_files)" -gt 0 ]]; then
            mv "$download_dir"/* "$files_dir"
        else
            echo "could not download files!"
        fi
    fi
}

if [[ "$hour" -ge "13" ]] && [[ "$hour" -le "18" ]]
then
    getfiles 12

elif [[ $hour -ge "19" ]] && [[ $hour -le "23" ]]
    getfiles 18
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite. While wget has the same url for both "if" and "else", the patterns it recognizes are different. What do the "getfiles 12" and "18" correspond to? Also what does "$1" correspond to in the code?

Comment: I created a "getfiles" function that is passed one argument (that's the `$1`). In you code you set $datetime with a 12 or a 18 (I assume that's the hour) -- that's the parameter that gets passed to the function. I didn't see the different pattern, I'll edit my code.

Comment: Thank you very much, Glenn. :-)